Raster (L2 Aster) geolocation problem
I am working with L2 Aster data that I downloaded from EarthData https://cmr.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/concepts/C1299783608-LPDAAC_ECS.html
I downloaded them as .tiff files.
When I try to open them, I have an error regarding geolocation, it seems it is missing a datum. Here is how the geo information looks like
ENGCRS["Universal Transverse Mercator CLARKE 1866 ELLIPSOID",EDATUM[""],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["easting",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["northing",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
I am trying to fix this using
Trial 1
gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=NAD27 +units=m +ellps=clrk66 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0" -t_srs EPSG:4326 -r bilinear -of GTiff "$input_file" "$output_file"
Trial 2
Just modifying to a CRS that is most likely suitable (UTM Zone 19S with WGS84)
correct_crs = CRS.from_epsg(32719)
meta['crs'] = correct_crs
I have good results, but the location seems to be shifted a few meters to the west when compared to basemaps on QGIS.
What am I doing wrong? how can I fix this?
